# REST Endpoints moving to pending state in warp

Tags: rust, warp

I have a warp server that servers 3 routes, one is a post while the other two are gets. I have my server set up in the following manner,

```
let serve = warp::serve(
    routes::index_route()
            .or(post_routes(data))
            .or(get_routes())
            .recover(move |error: Rejection| { 
                error::handle_rejection(error) 
        })
        .with(warp::cors().allow_any_origin())
);

serve.run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 8080)).await;
```

The issue is my post_route is a bit heavy on the computation side and each
call takes a while to complete. During that time while the post route completes
executing all the instructions the get_routes are in pending state and I am not being able to query the `get_routes` when the post route is being executed.Is there a way
to prevent this from happening?

Comment: it sounds like your `post_routes` blocks the executor but it's impossible to say without more context. Is the work `post_routes` does handled on a worker thread?

Comment: The post_routes is blocking the others, Its handled on a worker thread

Comment: So you are using `tokio::task::spawn_blocking` for the computation heavy work that `post_routes` does?

Comment: No I am not using tokio::task::spawn_blocking. Actually just checked I am not spawning any thread by myself. `post_routes` is equal to. 

 warp::path!("my_path")        
            .and(warp::post())
            .and(json_body())
            .and(warp::path::end())
            .and_then(move |data| my_func(
                data
            ));

Comment: Again, I cannot say for certain the solution here. But if you are doing computationally heavy work (or waiting without using async), it should be handled in a context where blocking is okay (`tokio::task::spawn_blocking`). The golden rule of async rust is to never block the executor.

Comment: I solved the problem using tokio::task::spawn_blocking. Thanks!